# modifying the persistence.xml at runtime

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I've searched for an answer to my problem on google and various forums, but couldn't find a solution. I'm currently trying to modify the persistence.xml at runtime by adding a persistence unit to the file.
The solutions for this question were always "pass a Map of properties when creating an EntityManagerFactory (or EntityManager)" but i need to save the new persistence unit in the persistence.xml, because the application is going to have 100 or even more persistence unit's, one for each tenant that will register to the service, each tenant will have his own database. I'm currently using EclipseLink 2.3.3 as my JPA implementation, EJB 3.1 and jboss 7.1.1.Final as my application server.
Is it possible to modify the persistence.xml at runtime (on the fly)?

Answer (score 2):

The persistence.xml is a deployed artifact, so would be difficult to modify at runtime.  I think passing a properties map to createEntityManagerFactory is your best solution, what issue are you having with this?

You may also want to try using the PersistenceProvider API, createContainerEntityManagerFactory() that takes a PersistenceUnitInfo.

Also, consider using EclipseLink's multi-tenant support,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/multitenancy.htm

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'm using the createContainerEntityManagerFactory() to create a container managed EntityManager, my issue is that i don't have the number of tenants or the databases created for the tenants at deployment time(I'm implementing a database strategy) so I need to create the persistence unit at runtime, and save it in case something happened to the server and needed to be restarted.